# how to alter table column in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 1 table in that i want to reorder the views column using alter function in my php file basically it should be reorder in most views to least views order.and want it to display in same order has altered but it is showing in order of id.

Now here i dont want to use ORDER BY views DESC thats why i am using alter function. because i am using ORDER BY name ASC already in my php file.

TABLE => users

```
 id   |  name  | views
  1   |  user1 |  700
  2   |  user3 |  900
  3   |  user1 |  200
  4   |  user4 |  900
  5   |  user4 |  800
  6   |  user4 |  800
  7   |  user3 |  900
  8   |  user4 |  900
  9   |  user5 |  100
 10   |  user5 |  100


// this is random table..//
```

ULtimately i am looking for that when by table is in views ORDERED then i will select data from table and if there are same name then it should be order in views as ALTERED so that i get ouptup like this :

```
 id   |  name  | views
  1   |  user1 |  900
  2   |  user1 |  700
  3   |  user1 |  200
  4   |  user3 |  900
  5   |  user4 |  900
  6   |  user4 |  800
  7   |  user5 |  900
  8   |  user5 |  900
  9   |  user5 |  300
 10   |  user5 |  100
```

Comment: I think you mean `UPDATE`, `ALTER` is used to change the table schema.

Comment: You can have multiple ORDER BY criteria's in your query: `ORDER BY name ASC, views DESC`. That will first order it by name, then it will order it by views (but still keep the name order, since that order is first).

Comment: yup ,but by default it display data in order of id

Comment: do this will work accordin to my requirement

Comment: first i want to order by name and if there are any same names then order that rows in order of views.

Comment: "yup ,but by default it display data in order of id" What default? SQL doesnt have a default sorting without using ORDER BY

Comment: If you don't supply an "ORDER BY", you can never be 100% what the order you're getting will be.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson without ORDER BY, you CAN be 100% sure what you will get... and that will be 100% chaos.

Comment: @Tarusjo - _"first i want to order by name and if there are any same names then order that rows in order of views"_ - That's what the ORDER BY I suggested will give you.

Comment: @IncredibleHat - Hehe. I stand corrected ;-)

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables are unordered sets. They have no intrinsic order, and you should never rely on any order returned from queries that don't explicitly state an `order by` clause. In your case, it seems you need two elements in the ordering - first by name, and then by views:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY name ASC, views DESC
```

Comment: should be `ASC` @Tarusjo

Comment: @Tarusjo it was supposed to be `ASC`. Stupid typo on my behalf, now edited and fixed by Gordon.